# C - pass uninitialised variable to function

Tags: c, function, pointers, initialization, declaration

Let's say I have a `char * str` and I don't know its size yet, so I can only declare it. Then I pass it to a function, this function will know the size of it so it will initialize and set it. How can I do this?

```
char * str;
func(&str);
```

and

```
void func(char ** str) {
    // initialize str...
}
```

Comment: downvoters - take just a second to give a reason.

Comment: there is no magic in allocating memory for a variable.  At some point, and by some method, you have to provide the _size_ value so the arguments of functions such as `malloc()` or `calloc()` can be called correctly.  ***It would also be good if you posted the code you have so far, showing at least some effort to solve the problem.***

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that. I added some code to clarify the question for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define SIZE 10  //or some other value
```

or

```
const int SIZE = 10;   //or some other value
```

Then:

```
void init( char** ptr) // pass a pointer to your char*
{
    *ptr= malloc( SIZE ); //of any size
}

int main()
{
    char *str;
    init( &str ); //address of pointer str
    //...Processing

    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd upvote if you removed `sizeof(char)`...

Comment: @PaulGriffiths yeah, I agree C defines `sizeof(char)` to be 1, always (and C++ does as well), but I think OP is a beginner, so I added. Anyway I would use `char *ptr = malloc(SIZE* sizeof(*ptr));`

Comment: +1 for `sizeof(*ptr)`